# Assign specific Exchange Role to App-only authentication with Exchange Online Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline, rbac

I need to use the following cmdlets from ExchangeOnline Powershell module with an unattended connection.

- Get-QuarantineMessage
- Preview-QuarantineMessage
- Release-QuarantineMessage
- Export-QuarantineMessage

1. Following this first documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps, I created an Azure App registration with self-signed certificate, assigned the "Exchange.ManageAsApp" API permission, then grant consent.
2. Then I created an Azure Security Group and add my application as a member of this group.
3. Then I created a Custom Role in Microsoft 365 Defender portal following this documentation:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/defender-for-identity/role-groups
4. In this role, I added the following custom permission:

- Email quarantine (manage)
- Email advanced actions (manage)
  And Read-Only for **Raw Data (Email & collaboration)**

5. And of course, I assigned my group created at step 2 to this new role

All of this allow me to use the first 2 cmdlets without any issue but I can't get access to the **Export-QuarantineMessage** and **Release-QuarantineMessage**.

We can list permissions needed for this cmdlet through those commands (from there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/find-exchange-cmdlet-permissions?view=exchange-ps)

```
PS > $Perms = Get-ManagementRole -Cmdlet Export-QuarantineMessage
PS > $Perms | foreach {Get-ManagementRoleAssignment -Role $_.Name -Delegating $false | Format-Table -Auto Role,RoleAssigneeType,RoleAssigneeName}

Role           RoleAssigneeType RoleAssigneeName
----           ---------------- ----------------
Security Admin RoleGroup        Organization Management
Security Admin RoleGroup        SecurityAdmins_782500194



Role              RoleAssigneeType RoleAssigneeName
----              ---------------- ----------------
Transport Hygiene RoleGroup        Hygiene Management
Transport Hygiene RoleGroup        Organization Management
```

I tried this last command :

```
PS > Add-RoleGroupMember "Hygiene Management" -Member <name of the application created at step 1>
```

I can see my application member if I run :

```
PS > Get-RoleGroupMember "Hygiene Management"
```

But I still don't have access to the the **Export-QuarantineMessage** and **Release-QuarantineMessage** cmdlets.

**UPDATE**

I try the following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#assign-custom-exchange-online-role-groups-to-the-application-using-service-principals

1. Creating a custom Exchange Role with "Transport Hygiene" + "Security Administrator"
2. PS > $AadApp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString ""

   PS > New-ServicePrincipal -AppId $AadApp.AppId -ServiceId $AadApp.ObjectId -DisplayName "ServicePrincipal For my app"

   PS > $SP = Get-ServicePrincipal -Identity "ServicePrincipal For my app"

   PS > Add-RoleGroupMember -Identity "<role created a step 1>" -Member $SP.Identity

Without any luck.

**UPDATE**
Changing my custom Exchange Role with only:
-Mailbox Import Export
-Mailbox Search
-MailboxSearchApplication
-Message Tracking
-Transport Hygiene
-View-Only Configuration
-View-Only Recipients
seems to work. I will let go the week-end to see if this is not another changes that take time to replicate on microsoft-side

Comment: Not familiar with Azure app, but if you want to manage the quarantine message you could refer to the permission mentioned in the following document：
Manage quarantined messages and files as an admin - Office 365 | Microsoft Learnhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/quarantine-admin-manage-messages-files?view=o365-worldwide